# What is a higher module regarding modules in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, module

I have this error in console ( ignore the detailed names, it's messed up now):

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type EventPageNavComponent is part
>   of the declarations of 2 modules: EventTasksModule and EventsModule!
>   Please consider moving EventPageNavComponent to a higher module that
>   imports EventTasksModule and EventsModule. You can also create a new
>   NgModule that exports and includes EventPageNavComponent then import
>   that NgModule in EventTasksModule and EventsModule.

Regarding the first solution, If I have module `A` and `B`. Does this mean, if I generate them under module `C`:

```
ng generate module C/A
ng generate module C/B
```

Make sure importing `A` and `B` in `C`, that makes `C` higher? Then declaring a new component in `C`, and `A` and `B` doesn't need to declare the component in order to use it?

The reason I ask is because, I cannot make this work.

Comment: Why did you put your component in declarations of two different module? If you need to use them under both, just declare it in one of them and export it, then import first module in your second module.

Comment: Then your way creates an import-one-direction-dependency between these 2 modules, you can't import in the other direction in future. It falls to error( circular import )

Comment: If you need to share components between these modules then create another one and import that module everywhere. In fact, you should have a SharedModule and put common components, directives in that module.

Comment: Sure. That is the 2nd way. That's why I am asking for the first way to solve this. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Hao, I also trying to figure out how to make it work with mysterious "higher" module, did you find some solution for this?

Comment: No, still didn't.